# Changing background with OpenGl and GLPaint example

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics, opengl-es

I am using Apple's provided example of OpenGl GLPaint, I did brush width, colors select, without big problems, but can't find any way how I could change background color to image.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a clear color using `glClearColor` in your `initGL` method.